# How to remove audio player styles added by mediaelement.js JavaScript?

Tags: css, javascript, media, audio

I'm working with the mediaelement.js CSS in WordPress and noticed a style attribute is being added to my `.mejs-container` element. I assume this is being added via JavaScript because the width and height values seem to be dynamic.

This is what is being output in my source:

```
<div id="mep_0" class="mejs-container svg mejs-audio" tabindex="0" role="application" aria-label="Audio Player" style="width: 453px;height: 62px;">
...
</div>
```

I tried writing some CSS to override but the style attribute is taking precedence so this approach doesn't work:

```
.mejs-container {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
```

How can I stop this style attribute being added?

Comment: Try to remove the event listener

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score -2):

```
<script>
    $('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','tracks','volume','fullscreen']});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you explain why will this help?